# Knockout nested foreach with filters

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to add a foreach filter inside another foreach, let's say I have a first foreach with Employees, I need to add another foreach based on employee number, so for each employee I need to filter the orders related to each one. How can I filter my second foreach by employee number on my view and loop through all employee orders?

This is my view:

```
<div>   
<table id="employee-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 15px" class="sorting_disabled"></th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled">"EmployeeName"</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled">EmployeeNumber</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled">Address</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled">EmployeePosition</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled">OfficeName</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled">TotalCharges</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- ko foreach: model.employeeList() -->
        <tr>                                
            <td data-bind="css: { 'dashboard-collapsed-triangle': $data.numberOfOrders > 0 },
                         click: function () { $('#employee-service-cost-table' + $data.employeeId).toggle(); $(this).toggleClass('dashboard-collapsed-triangle dashboard-expanded-triangle') }" >&nbsp;
            </td>                                
            <td><a href="#tips"><span class="dashboard-employee-selectable" data-bind="text: $data.employeeName"></span></a></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data.employeeNumber"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data.address"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data.employeePosition"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data.officeName"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: $data.totalCharges"></span></td>
        </tr>

        <!-- HERE I NEED A SECOND FOREACH -->
            <tr style="display: none; background-color: aliceblue" data-bind="attr: { 'id': 'employee-service-cost-table' + $data.employeeId }">
                <td></td>                                
                <td colspan="3"><span data-bind="text: $data.OrderNumber"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: $data.Description"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: $data.TotalCharges"></span></td>
                <td><span data-bind="text: $data.Date"></span></td>                                            
            </tr>
        <!-- END SECOND FOREACH -->

        <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the $data parameter to the second-level foreach.

If you keep orders in a separate array just use:

```
<!-- ko foreach: getOrders($data.employeeId) -->
```

where getOrders is a function which will filter out orders for particular employee.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you have a list of employees and a list of orders. One employee can then have multiple orders based on the employee id?

One way to do this is to group the orders by employee id:

```
model.ordersByEmployeeId = ko.computed(function() {
    var ordersByEmployeeId = {};
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(model.orders(), function(order) {
        var employeeId = ko.unwrap(order.employeeId);
        if (!ordersByEmployeeId[employeeId]) {
            ordersByEmployeeId[employeeId] = [];
        }
        ordersByEmployeeId[employeeId].push(order);
    });
    return ordersByEmployeeId;
});
```

Then your loops would look as follows:

```
<!-- ko foreach: model.employeeList() -->
...
    <!-- ko foreach: $root.ordersByEmployeeId()[$data.employeeId] -->
    ...
```

Comment: yes one employee can have multiple orders, do I need a computed field for that? or I can do the filter directly on the view?

Comment: You could do it in your view, but you generally want as little logic inside your view as possible.